# Requests can't click on a checkpoint when logging in

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello so I have a Python script where I log into Instagram via requests. I get the return:

```
{"message": "checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url": "/challenge/9212574816/8B3Vfvw19J/", "lock": false, "status": "fail"}
```

As it is asking to verify my identity. How could I go about clicking the button to verify my login? Can I use requests.post and how so? I allow redirects and am wondering if anyone ever came across this problem with requests too. Should I import selenium and use get xpath?

Answer (score 0):

You cant click a button with the requests module.
You can either use the DevTools to check the network activity that happens when you click the button manually and then send a request to that URL.

Or you can use Selenium to simulate a real browser that can render html and javascript.